# This is a bug in sbcl?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, literals, sbcl, clos

Why happen this in sbcl? Maybe a bug?

```
(defclass myclass ()
  ((s1
    :initform '((a . 1) (b . 2))) 
   (s2
    :initform '((a . 1) (b . 2)))))

(defparameter ins (make-instance 'myclass))

(setf (cdr (assoc 'a (slot-value ins 's1))) 43) ;; change only slot s1

;; here my problem

(slot-value ins 's1)  ;; => ((a . 44) (b . 2)))
(slot-value ins 's2)  ;; => ((a . 44) (b . 2)))
```

But if change :initform  to :

```
(defclass myclass ()
  ((s1
    :initform '((a . 1) (b . 2))) 
   (s2
    :initform '((a . 1) (b . 3)))))
```

The problem disappears

I test this in **sbcl 1.4.3** and **1.4.11**. In clisp it seems that the problem does not arise.

Comment: Try: `(eq (slot-value ins 's1) (slot-value ins 's2))` and notice what it returns.

Comment: It's allowed space optimization of static list data.

Answer (score 13):

No.  You are modifying literal data, which has undefined consequences.

When you quote a list in source code, it means that the thing you want to work with is exactly the list that the reader produced from your source code—this is a literal list.  Such things may be remembered by the reader so that two identical lists are not duplicated.

One way to fix this is to create the lists at runtime, using `list` and `cons`:

```
(defclass myclass ()
  ((s1
    :initform (list (cons a 1) (cons b 2))) 
   (s2
    :initform (list (cons a 1) (cons b 2)))))
```

Comment: I get it, thanks for the help!!, I started to learn CL recently and I still work to understand some things

Answer (score 9):

This is not a bug. `'((a . 1) (b . 2))` is a literal constant and as all constants assumed immutable. That means all occurrences of `'(a . 1)` that also are literal can just point to the `car` of the other one since **it should never change**

Now implementations can choose to make new structures so CLISP might do that, but you cannot rely on this. You should not mutate literal data.

If you are going to change it you need to use a deep copy, like this:

```
(defclass myclass ()
  ((s1
    :initform (copy-tree '((a . 1) (b . 2)))) 
   (s2
    :initform (copy-tree '((a . 1) (b . 2))))))
```

Comment: Another problem is that even if these two assoc lists are different, they are not newly instantiated for each new instance of `myclass`.

Comment: @Kaz True, but `copy-tree` still is the medicine :-)

Comment: `copy-alist` is lighter on the stomach, and applicable here, though not as broad an antibiotic.