# Specification of conses

Tags: common-lisp

The Wikipedia-page about [car and cdr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR) says that a `cons` is a pair of pointers.

The following code seems to confirm that:

```el
(progn
  (setq a '(1 . 2))
  (setq b a)
  (setf (car b) 10)
  (print a))
```

The evaluation of that form gives the cons `(10 . 2)`. Setting the `car` of `b` changes the `car` of `a`. You can try that in the [online repl at compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lisp_online.php).

Where is that behavior defined in the [Common Lisp specification](http://cvberry.com/tech_writings/notes/common_lisp_standard_draft.html)?

(I've read some of the text but couldn't find the section pin-pointing that behavior.)

Interestingly the Wikipedia page on conses says "`cons` constructs memory objects which hold two **values** or pointers to values". If the atom 1 would directly be stored in the cons object then changing `b` wouldn't change `a`, would it?

I assume above that `a` and `b` hold the cons objects and not pointer to conses.
Even if the actual lisp implementation works with pointers this should not be visible on repl-level or should it according to the spec? One could achieve a similar effect when one assumes that `a` and `b` hold pointers that both point to the same `cons`.
`Consing`, i.e., the construction of lists through repeated application of `cons`, supports the assumption that conses are represented by pointers in symbol values.

The following two forms are equivalent:

```el
(let ((a '(1)))
  (setq b (cons 2 a)))
```

```el
(setq b '(2 1))
```

Comment: C is a pass by value language and CL is a pass by value language. That means when applying functions the expressions used as arguments are no longer expressions (or variables) but values that then gets bound to the names in that function. That the values are address pointers has nothing to do with it. Perhaps you should look at pass by name and see how that differs from pass by value.

Comment: @Sylwester The pointers are just an auxiliary means for describing the effect I assumed that if the authors of Wikipedia may use that means I may use it too.

Answer (score 5):

> Setting the car of b changes the car of a.

You are not setting the `car` of `b`. You are setting the `car` of the same cons cell which is referenced by `b` and `a`.

```
CL-USER 1 > (let (a b)
              (setq a (cons 1  2))
              (setq b a)

              (eq a b))
T
```

Explanation:

- we have variables `a` and `b`.
- `(cons 1 2)` returns a cons cell
- `(setq a (cons 1 2))` sets a to the result of `(cons 1 2)`, a cons cell.
- `(setq b a)` evaluates `a`, which returns above cons cell and sets `b` to that cons cell.

The key to understand is that evaluation of variables and functions returns non-primitive (that is other than primitive numbers, characters, ...) objects as themselves - not as a copy.

> I assume above that a and b hold the cons objects and not pointer to conses.

That's wrong. `a` and `b` are variables, which just point to both the same single cons cell.

> "cons constructs memory objects which hold two values or pointers to values"

In a Common Lisp implementation something like small numbers (fixnums) might be stored directly in a cons cell. One can not reliably compare numbers by identity (using `EQ`) and has to do numeric comparison (`EQL`, `=`, ...).

OTOH, cons cells can't be stored inside cons cells and thus are referenced by pointers internally.

The operations you use:

- [SETQ](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_setq.htm#setq) : *First form1 is evaluated and the result is stored in the variable var1*. -> Notice how it says: *result* and not *copy of the result*.
- [RPLCA](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rplaca.htm#rplaca) - this is what `(setf CAR)` actually uses. : *rplaca replaces the car of the cons with object* and *The cons is modified* -> thus it modifies the cons object it gets passed as an argument.
- [Evaluation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_a.htm) - since you execute your code, the rules for evaluation apply.

Further useful to understand the execution model of Lisp:

- An old Lisp book: 'Anatomy of LISP' by John Allen. ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007001115X))
- A Scheme spec like [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/).
- [Lisp in small pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces), a book explaining the execution models of Scheme/Lisp and their implementation.

Comment: Thx. You are right. The phrase "Setting the `car` of `b` changes the `car` of `a`." is a lax formulation. I meant Setting the `car` of the value of `a` changes the `car` of the value of `b`. Since we are speaking about language specification I should use a correct language. I will improve the question in that respect. IMHO when discussing the implementation of some application one would seldom (never?) use the strictly correct version "the car of the value of `a`".

Comment: Regarding: "\"I assume above that a and b hold the cons objects and not pointer to conses.\" That's wrong. a and b are variables, which just point to both the same single cons cell." That bit of the answer is close to the actual question: "Where is that behavior defined in the Common Lisp specification?" (The double pointer version for a cons stored as value is equivalent to the stored pointer to a cons of two values if you can't access the pointers. But that is implementation detail.) The mention of pointers is just for describing the effects. Where is the def for the effects in the spec?

Comment: @Tobias: effects of what exactly? Which operation are you interested in?

Comment: In every implementation the value of a variable is part of the overall state of the machine. So assigning `b` the value of `a` always involves copying in some form. In that way the answer of Barmer is over-simplification. E.g., assigning the variable `b` defined as `int b;` in C the value of `a` (also with type `int`) copies the bit pattern from the storage of `a` to the storage of `b`. Even so this is passing by value. Assume `car` would be implemented as higher bits of `a` and the `cdr` as the lower then modifying `(car b)` would not modify `(car a)`.

Comment: C has a different evaluation model. Lisp is not machine oriented. Assigning B the value of A means in Lisp: *binding B to the value of A*. There is no talk about memory, pointers, copying, bit patterns, storage, ... . Lisp is using a model of *bindings to values*. 'Assume car would be implemented as higher bits of a ' -> that makes no sense, since in Lisp `a` has a binding, but no bits. `a` has no storage for data.

Comment: The Scheme spec. r5rs says: "An identifier may name a type of syntax, or it may name a location where a value can be stored... An identifier that names a location is called a variable and is said to be *bound to that location*. The value stored in the location to which a variable is bound is called the variable's value. By abuse of terminology, the variable is sometimes said ... to be bound to the value. This is not quite accurate, but confusion rarely results from this practice." Does Scheme differ from CL in that respect? Scheme is a small and clean Lisp dialect. So I start there.

Comment: Practically the wording makes no difference when it comes to what you were asking. Differences between Scheme and CL exist. CL has dynamic and lexical binding. CL has a separate namespace for functions.

Comment: It would make a difference when `a` and `b` are bound to the same location where the cons is stored as value.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your code is invalid because you're not allowed to modify constant lists. It should be:

```
(progn
  (setq a (cons 1  2))
  (setq b a)
  (setf (car b) 10)
  (print a))
```

When you perform an assignment like `(setq b a)`, it sets the value of `b` to be the same as the value of `a`. The specification of `SETQ` says nothing about making a copy of the value, so the two variables contain the *same* value, which in this case is a cons cell.

Setting the car of that cons cell modifies that object -- again, there's no copying being done. So you'll see the change through any variable that refers to the cons cell, or any other reference (it could be in a structure slot, an array element, another cons cell, etc.).

I don't think the specification ever actually comes out and says that these things are all the same, it's just implicit in the fact that we're passing around abstract objects, and no copying is done unless you call a function that's explicitly defined to do so (e.g. `COPY-TREE`).

The specification doesn't talk about pointers, but that's generally what's going on under the covers. A cons cell is like a C structure:

```
typedef struct cons {
    lisp_object car,
    lisp_object cdr
} cons;
```

`lisp_object` would probably be a union of various types (some immediate types for things like `FIXNUM`, and pointers for other types). When a variable contains a `cons`, it actually contains a pointer to the above structure, and the assignment copies the pointer, not the structure. So the Lisp code is analogous to C code like:

```
cons *a = make_cons(1, 2);
cons *b = a;
b->car = 10;
printf("%d\n", a->car);
```

Comment: About your "first of all": I come from the elisp corner where that code is perfectly valid (AFAIK). To ensure that common lisp handles the code in the same way I tried it at [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lisp_online.php) with GNU CLisp v2.49+. It evaluated the code exactly as I expected it with no errors or warnings. After reading your answer I searched the net for GNU CLisp command line switches that increase the warning levels without luck. Since that problem is only a secondary battlefield I will correct it ASAP.

Comment: @Tobias: executing example code in some implementation is not a way to explore 'undefined behavior' - a particular implementation may have that behavior by chance in the way you execute it, but in other implementations and other situations it may behave differently. 'you are not allowed to modify constant lists' might be not a wording to explain it. Better: 'the various effects of modification of constant lists are undefined'. From that follows that we should not modify constant lists, since we don't know what exactly will happen when we do it in certain situations.

Comment: @Tobias: possible effects of modifying data constants: it works as intended, other data is modified too, the program detects it and throws an error, the program crashes, ... - relatively often in Lisp implementations we see the effect 'other data is modified too', since Common Lisp file compilers are allowed to optimize space, by sharing literal data when they detect that the literal data is equal to other literal data or parts of it...

Comment: With respect to "first of all": I should be more careful. After your hint I found in the [elisp-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html#Rearrangement): "A common pitfall is to use a quoted constant list as a non-last argument to ‘nconc’.  If you do this, your program will change each time you run it!" together with an example program where the used constant list changes. (Detected with `symbol-function`.) Thx,... Always learning...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086082/this-is-a-bug-in-sbcl/52086216#52086216) for an example of the pitfall Rainer referred to.